# Retrieve Cassandra row counts faster

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax

We have set up our cassandra cluster as 3 nodes in aws ec2 instances. Each instance is of type t2.large

We need to get counts of row from a cassandra table.

We loaded a table in cassandra with 900k records. We have around 91 columns in this table. Most of the records are text datatype.
All these 900k records were part of a single partition key.

When we tried a select count(*) query with that partition key, the query was timing out.

However we were able to retrieve counts through multiple calls by fetching only 100k records in each call. The only disadvantage here is the time taken which is around 1 minute and 3 seconds.

Is there any other approach to get the row count faster in cassandra? Do we need to change the data modelling approach to achieve this?

Comment: Data modeling warning: having 9 hundred thousand rows in a single partition is bad, especially if heavy things are inside. Mostly probably you better split it into multiple partitions, only then you really will be using benefits of Cassandra.

"a good rule of thumb is to keep the maximum number of values below 100,000 items and the disk size under 100MB."

Comment: Please try to avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood.

Comment: @HadesArchitect : The primary key design for our table is ((organization_id, entity_type), container_id). All datatypes are text. We need to arrange the container_id-clustering key in asc or desc order and display. We fear, if we introduce another column say month in partition key, we may lose the overall sorting order of container_ids.

Answer (score 0):

Hades Architect is correct.  You will definitely want to rethink your data model.

With Cassandra, more partitions helps with better data distribution.  On the other hand, large partitions can dramatically slow down the disk read process.  As the partition grows it will eventually become unusable.

> Is there any other approach to get the row count faster in cassandra?

Yes.  The [DSBulk](https://github.com/datastax/dsbulk) tool has built-in mechanisms which work with the partition ranges of a cluster and can read/count all rows.

```
dsbulk count \
    -k keyspacename \
    -t tablename \
    -u username \
    -p password \
    -h 10.0.0.2
```